# Why stream numbers generated by r.stream.order go one after other, not succeeding

Tags: grass-gis, stream-order

Subwatersheds and streams corresponding form an 2n+1 series, where n=0,1,2...
I don't know for what reason, and I also doubt if it works like that in all cases.
It's very useful for me as I would like to insert some numbers between and so won't need any renumeration. But I should be certain about the algorythm.

UPD: To be clear.
When r.stream.order generates attribute table, it gives:
cat   stream next_stream
2 2 ...
4 4 ...
6 6 ... ...
Where are 3,5,7 subwatershed and whether it will be always so?

Comment: Sorry, not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `r.watershed` has the added feature that it can produce "half basins" (each basin split in the middle by the enclosed drainage line). This is what causes even numbering of cat values for both output watersheds and streams. In the `r.watershed` man page is the explanation:

*The output half_basin raster map stores each half-basin is given a unique value. Watershed basins are divided  into  left  and  right  sides.  The right-hand  side  cell  of  the watershed basin (looking upstream) are given even values corresponding to the values in basin.  The left-hand side cells of the watershed basin are given odd values which are one less than the value of the watershed basin.*

The raster values of all **full** basins and streams get only the even values, to differentiate from the other half basin, and these raster cell values are then carried through to the vector layers, so you end up with only even cat values for all streams.

This output can be used further in the RUSLE hydrological drainage model. So I would not try to manipulate the cat values nor try to insert other values in between.

Comment: Uh.. sad. So I have to renumerate every chain of subwatersheds, that is above of my custom point added to preserve the order? It's very sophisticated for even 10 points.
r.watershed doesn't have any option to create subwatersheds not only at streams' outlets but also at custom gage points?

Comment: I usually just run `r.water.outlet` in a loop over the gauge locations.